# ios7 link invoking wrong url on click

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, ios7

I have a checkbox hidden behind a label. When I click on the label the code updates the value in checkbox. This works fine in Windows but iOS7 is not clicking the checkbox, instead it opens random social sites like Facebook and twitter.

http://jsfiddle.net/skhatoon/2Cmfe/

```
$(function () {
        var Note = function (noteText) {
            this.text = ko.observable(noteText);
            this.dateTime = new Date();
        }

        var Challenge = function (challengeText, challengeCompleted) {
            this.text = ko.observable(challengeText);
            this.completed = ko.observable(challengeCompleted);
        }
var isTouch = false;
try { isTouch = "ontouchstart" in window; } catch (e) { }

var $activeTip = null;


jQuery.fn.customInput = function () {
    $(this).each(function (i) {
        if ($(this).is('[type=checkbox],[type=radio]')) {
            var input = $(this);
            if (input.data('customInput') === 'done') {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                input.data('customInput', 'done');
            }

            // get the associated label using the input's id
            var label = $('label[for=' + input.attr('id') + ']');

            //get type, for classname suffix 
            var inputType = (input.is('[type=checkbox]')) ? 'checkbox' : 'radio';

            // wrap the input + label in a div 
            $('<div class="custom-' + inputType + '"></div>').insertBefore(input).append(input, label);

            // find all inputs in this set using the shared name attribute
            var allInputs = $('input[name=' + input.attr('name') + ']');

            // necessary for browsers that don't support the :hover pseudo class on labels
            label.hover(
                function () {
                    $(this).addClass('hover');
                    if (inputType == 'checkbox' && input.is(':checked')) {
                        $(this).addClass('checkedHover');
                    }
                },
                function () { $(this).removeClass('hover checkedHover'); }
            );

            //bind custom event, trigger it, bind click,focus,blur events                   
            input.bind('updateState', function () {
                if (input.is(':checked')) {
                    if (input.is(':radio')) {
                        allInputs.each(function () {
                            $('label[for=' + $(this).attr('id') + ']').removeClass('checked');
                        });
                    };
                    label.addClass('checked');
                }
                else { label.removeClass('checked checkedHover checkedFocus'); }

            })
            .trigger('updateState')
            .click(function () {

                if (input.is(':checked')) {
                    if (input.is(':radio')) {
                        allInputs.each(function () {
                            $('label[for=' + $(this).attr('id') + ']').removeClass('checked');
                        });
                    };
                    label.addClass('checked');
                }
                else { label.removeClass('checked checkedHover checkedFocus'); }

            })
            .focus(function () {
                label.addClass('focus');
                if (inputType == 'checkbox' && input.is(':checked')) {
                    $(this).addClass('checkedFocus');
                }
            })
            .blur(function () { label.removeClass('focus checkedFocus'); });
        }
    });
};

    $.fn.smartHover = function (configObject) {
        if (isTouch) {
            $(this)
                .bind("hold", function () {
                    $activeTip = $(this);
                    $(this).data("held", true);
                })
                .bind("hold", configObject.over)
                .bind("click", function (e) {
                    var wasHeld = $(this).data("held");
                    $(this).data("held", false);
                    if (wasHeld) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        return false;
                    }
                })
                .data("close", configObject.out);
        } else {
            $(this).hoverIntent(configObject);
        }
    };

     if (isTouch) {
        document.ontouchstart = function () {
            if ($activeTip) {
                $activeTip.data("close").call($activeTip);
                $activeTip = null;
            }
        };
    }
        function courseViewModel(notes, challenges) {
              var self = this;

           self.termsOfUseAccepted = ko.observable(false);
               self.continueDisplay = ko.computed({
              read: function() {
              return self.termsOfUseAccepted();
                //return self.termsOfUseAccepted();

              },
              owner: this,
              deferEvaluation: true
              });

              self.studentsName = ko.observable('Garry Smith');
              self.studentsAge = ko.observable(25);
              self.notes = ko.observableArray(notes);

              self.challenges = ko.observableArray(
              ko.utils.arrayMap(challenges, function (challenge) {
                  return new Challenge(challenge.challengeText, challenge.completed);
              }));

              self.challengeCompletedCount = ko.computed(function () {
                  return ((ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.challenges(), 
    function (challenge)    {
                      return challenge.completed();
                  }).length / self.challenges().length) * 100).toFixed(0) + ' %';
              });

              self.noteToAdd = ko.observable();

              self.addNote = function () {
                  var note = self.noteToAdd();
                  if (note) {
                      self.notes.push(new Note(note));
                      self.noteToAdd("");

   function showtip() {
            if ($(this).hasClass("checkbox")) {
                $(this).addClass('show-tip');
            }                           
   }
   function hidetip() {
            if ($(this).hasClass("checkbox")) {
                 $(this).removeClass('show-tip');
            }                           
   }

    var config = {
            sensitivity: 4,
            interval: 250,
            over: showtip,
            out: hidetip
        };    
 $(".checkbox").smartHover(config);    

                      self.validation("success", true, "Wicked good job!");
                  }
                  else {
                       self.validation("fail", true, "Oh shux! There was no note text.");   
                  }
              };
              self.validationStatus = ko.observable(); 
              self.displayValidation = ko.observable();
              self.validationText = ko.observable();

              self.validation = function (status, displayValidation, text) {
                  self.validationStatus(status);
                  self.displayValidation(displayValidation);
                  self.validationText(text);
              };                  
          };

      var notes = [{
          text: 'test1'
      }, {
          text: 'test2'
      }];
      var challenges = [{
          "challengeText": "Chapter 1 Challenge",
          "completed": false
      }, {
          "challengeText": "Chapter 2 Challenge",
          "completed": false
      }, {
          "challengeText": "Chapter 3 Challenge",
          "completed": false
      }, {
          "challengeText": "Chapter 4 Challenge",
          "completed": false
      }, {
          "challengeText": "Chapter 5 Challenge",
          "completed": false
      }, {
          "challengeText": "Chapter 6 Challenge",
          "completed": false
      }];

      var viewModel = new courseViewModel(notes, challenges);
      ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
$('input').customInput();
  });

(function($) {
    $.fn.hoverIntent = function(f, g) {
        var cfg = {sensitivity: 7,interval: 100,timeout: 0};
        cfg = $.extend(cfg, g ? {over: f,out: g} : f);
        var cX, cY, pX, pY;
        var track = function(ev) {
            cX = ev.pageX;
            cY = ev.pageY
        };
        var compare = function(ev, ob) {
            ob.hoverIntent_t = clearTimeout(ob.hoverIntent_t);
            if ((Math.abs(pX - cX) + Math.abs(pY - cY)) < cfg.sensitivity) {
                $(ob).unbind("mousemove", track);
                ob.hoverIntent_s = 1;
                return cfg.over.apply(ob, [ev])
            } else {
                pX = cX;
                pY = cY;
                ob.hoverIntent_t = setTimeout(function() {
                    compare(ev, ob)
                }, cfg.interval)
            }
        };
        var delay = function(ev, ob) {
            ob.hoverIntent_t = clearTimeout(ob.hoverIntent_t);
            ob.hoverIntent_s = 0;
            return cfg.out.apply(ob, [ev])
        };
        var handleHover = function(e) {
            var ev = jQuery.extend({}, e);
            var ob = this;
            if (ob.hoverIntent_t) {
                ob.hoverIntent_t = clearTimeout(ob.hoverIntent_t)
            }
            if (e.type == "mouseenter") {
                pX = ev.pageX;
                pY = ev.pageY;
                $(ob).bind("mousemove", track);
                if (ob.hoverIntent_s != 1) {
                    ob.hoverIntent_t = setTimeout(function() {
                        compare(ev, ob)
                    }, cfg.interval)
                }
            } else {
                $(ob).unbind("mousemove", track);
                if (ob.hoverIntent_s == 1) {
                    ob.hoverIntent_t = setTimeout(function() {
                        delay(ev, ob)
                    }, cfg.timeout)
                }
            }
        };
        return this.bind('mouseenter', handleHover).bind('mouseleave', handleHover)
    }
})(jQuery);
```

And now following is my HTML

```
<!--pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root, null, 2)"></pre-->

<input type="checkbox" id="terms"  data-bind="checked: termsOfUseAccepted" >
<label for="terms" class="" >I understand </label>
    <div class="chk-overview ">
     <a  href="javascript:;" data-bind="visible: continueDisplay">
        <h2 >Continue</h2>
    </a>
    </div>
     <div class="form-group">
<label>Students Name: <span class="text-primary" data-bind="text: studentsName"></span>
</label>
<input class="form-control" data-bind="value: studentsName, 
valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" />
<label>Student's Age: <span class="text-primary" data-bind="text: studentsAge"></span>
</label>
<input class="form-control" data-bind="value: studentsAge, valueUpdate:
 'afterkeydown'"     />
</div>
<hr />
<h5 data-bind="visible: challenges().length > 0">Challenges:</h5>

<div data-bind="template: { name: 'challenges-template', foreach: challenges }"></div>
<script type="text/html" id="challenges-template">
<div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox"
data-bind="checked: completed"><div data-bind="text: text"></div>
      </label></div>
</script>
<h5>Completed: <span data-bind="text: challengeCompletedCount"></span></h5>
<hr />
<div class="alert" data-bind="text: validationText, 
css: { 
    'alert-success': validationStatus() === 'success',
    'alert-danger': !(validationStatus() === 'success')
},
visible: displayValidation">
</div>
<form data-bind="submit: addNote">
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Add Note:</label>
    <textarea data-bind="value: noteToAdd" class="form-control"></textarea>
    <br />
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Add</button>
</div>
</form>
 <h5 >Notes:</h5>

<div data-bind="template: { name: 'notes-template', foreach: notes }"></div>

<script type="text/html" id="notes-template">
<div class="well well-small"> <h5 data-bind = "text: new Date()"> </h5>
      <div data-bind="text: text"></div > </div>
</script>
```

Comment: The first checkbox in the screen is the one which has a hidden checkbox.

Comment: There's probably something not shown in your code sample overlapping your label (and I doubt that the links are "random").

Comment: The full code is accessible in fiddle. The links are random, most of the time going to twitter and sometimes going to Facebook.

Comment: I don't think "random" means what you think it does. In any case, there are no mentions of either of those in your code sample, so they're coming from elsewhere.

Comment: I don't have any reference to facebook or twitter in my fiddle. The issue seems in Safari Mobile as Windows is working just fine.